# Change the order of pictures at midnight

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of picture ads that I want to change the order of every day at midnight.

Basically so that one day it will be like this

```
<img src="image1">
<img src="image2">
<img src="image3">
<img src="image4">
```

and the next day it will look like this

```
<img src="image4">
<img src="image1">
<img src="image2">
<img src="image3">
```

How could I accomplish this with javascript, jquery or php. Not concerned about what language I use, just need to figure it out. Thanks..

Comment: You just keep the order in file/database and change it every midnight. Any particular questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one  http://jsfiddle.net/KQwf2/1/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://solarpanels2green.com/images/one.gif" title='1'>
<img src="http://solarpanels2green.com/images/two.gif" title='2'>
<img src="http://solarpanels2green.com/images/three.gif" title='3'>
<img src="http://solarpanels2green.com/images/four.gif" title='4'>
```

and js code

```
var all = $('img'), 
        shift = Math.floor(
          (new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
         / (24 * 3600 * 1000)) % all.length;

all.filter(':gt(' + (all.length - shift - 1) + ')')
   .insertBefore(all.first());
```

It calculates the MOD of the division of number of days passed since the midnight of January 1, 1970 by the number of the elements in the images list, takes this amount of images from the bottom of the list and moves them in front of the list.

**Updated** to take into account the timezone of the visitor.

Comment: Beautiful, Thanks! Thanks to everyone else too. The other solutions seem like they would work, but this was too easy to implement to pass up.

Comment: @user1166556  You are welcome :) Actually, this `if (shift != 0)` could be also removed. It was a late evening, so I had a 'slow thinking' )

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a database, it would be a simple matter in php to store the order each day in the database. Then when the page loads, you check the date that the order is from and update if it does not match the current date. The update process would consist of generating a new order through php's [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

If you do not have access to a database, you will need to come up with a different randomization mechanism that is based solely around the date. One option would be to generate a hash of the date and use it to drive your ordering.

Here's some php pseudocode of the non-DB option:

```
$fullhash = md5(date("Ymd"));
$hash = $fullhash;
$countImages = 4; //or whatever the actual number of images you have is
$shownImages = array();
while ($countShown < $countImages) 
{
  $num = ord($hash); //get ascii value of first char of $hash
  $num = $num % $countImages; //convert the number to something that corresponds to an image
  if (!(in_array($num, $shownImages)))
  {
    echo "<img src='image" . $num . "'>";
    $shownImages[] = $num;
  }
  $hash = substr($hash,1);
  if (strlen($hash) == 0)
  {
    $fullhash = md5($fullhash); //generate a new hash in case the previous one did not catch all images
    $hash = $fullhash;
  }
}
```

This could seem overly complicated. If you can consistently set a seed for random number generation on your server, then you can replace most of the above code with that. However, more and more implementations are moving away from seed-it-yourself random number generators, which makes it less trivial to repeatably generate the same sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in PHP that only depends on the last-modification times of a set of images in a given directory:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b){
  $atime = filemtime($a);
  $btime = filemtime($b);

  return $atime == $btime ? 0 : ($atime < $btime ? -1 : 1);
}

$paths = array();

if ($dh = opendir('images')){
  while (($path = readdir($dh)) !== false){
    if (substr($path, -4) == '.jpg'){
      array_push($paths, "images/$path");
    }
  }
}

$count = count($paths);
$offset = time() % $count;

usort($paths, 'cmp');

for ($i = 0; $i < $offset; $i++){
  $path = array_shift($paths);
  array_push($paths, $path);
}

?>
```

Then, wherever you need it in your page:

```
<?php foreach ($paths as $path): ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" ... />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the time with javascript.  then i would create an array, randomize the order and output your images

```
var d = new Date();
var time= d.getHours();
if(time>=24){
  //code here for randomizing
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/randomorder.shtml

Comment: And what to do if `time < 24`?

Comment: nothing, you are looking to change order if the viewer is after midnight on his/her computer

Comment: @t q: 1. I'm not OP 2. You need to read the question once again, you didn't understand it